# abstract class and static methods

Tags: c++, abstract-class, static-methods

I have an abstract class:

```
class A
{
  public:
  bool loaded_;
  virtual int load() = 0;
}
```

And several derived classes :

```
class B:public A
{
  public:
  int load();
  static B& instance();
}  

class C:public A
{
  public:
  int load();
  static C& instance();
}
```

The fact is that the code inside ::instance() methods is the same for each class :

```
static B& B::instance()
{
  static B instance_;
  if (!instance_.loaded_)
  {
    instance_.load();
    instance_.loaded_=true;
  }
  return instance_;
}

static C& C::instance()
{
  static C instance_;
  if (!instance_.loaded_)
  {
    instance_.load();
    instance_.loaded_=true;
  }
  return instance_;
}
```

I would like to factorize this ::instance method, but given that it uses the virtual method ::load, i cannot define it in the class A. 
Theoretically, i know it's weird since the class A should have 0 instance and B,C should have 1 instance but it also makes sense that this code should be factorized.

How would you solve that problem ?

Comment: Look at using a template to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could make `instance()` a free function template:

```
template<class T>
T& instance()
{
  static T instance_;
  if (!instance_.loaded_)
  {
    instance_.load();
    instance_.loaded_=true;
  }
  return instance_;
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
instance<B>().do_stuff()
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a common usage of the CRTP, define the function that creates the instance in the template and then instantiate it in each type:

```
struct A {
   virtual ~A() {}     // don't forget to make your destructor virtual!
   virtual void load() = 0;
};
template <typename T>
struct instance_provider {
    static T& instance() { /* implementation */ }
};
struct B : A, instance_provider<B> {
   virtual void load();
};
struct C : A, instance_provider<C> {
   virtual void load();
};
```